# How to change the display format of datetime fields in the Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, datetime, format

I already read in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#datetime-format) that you have to change it in the settings and set `USE_L10N` to `False`. So i did it accordingly in 
`settings.py`:

```py
    USE_L10N = False
    DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd.m.Y - H:i:s'
    USE_TZ = True
    USE_I18N = True
    TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us
```

But my the datetime field of my objects are still displayed like this in the admin interface:

*2022-01-18 15:00:56.421123+00:00*

So why is the datetime still not displayed according to my settings.py, but like *Y-m-d H:i:s.u*?

In my `models.py` i implemented `__str__(self)` like this:

```py
    def __str__(self):
        return self.created
```

my **model**:

```py
    class My_model(models.Model):
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share your ModelAdmin? Datetime formatting will not be applied to the result of a model `__str__` method, you should specify the field explicitly in `list_display`

Comment: My **admin.py** just contains this:
`from .models import My_model`
`admin.site.register(My_model)`
@IainShelvington

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, thanks to [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington).

In admin.py I changed the model registration from

```py
admin.site.register(My_model)
```

to

```py
@admin.register(My_model)
class My_model_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('created')
```

Now the datetime format is represented in the table inside the admin interface properly:

| created |
| --- |
| 18.01.2022 - 16:00:56 |

It is displayed as 16:00:56 now, because I use *CET* in `settings.py`.